LSM6DS3 SPI-communication problem with STM32F4
I'm having trouble getting data from the LSM6DS3 sensor over 4-wire SPI. The datasheet says 4-wire SPI is the default, so I didn't send anything for the sensor settings, and immediately tried to read it.   When I try to read the value of the "WHO_AM_I" register, I get too short pulses in response that cannot be read.
I use this board.

4-wire SPI. Master - STM32F411.
LSM6DS3  to STM32F411
3v3      to  3,3 В
GND      to  GND
SA0      to  PA6 - SPI1 MISO
CS       to  PA4 - GPIOA4
SDA      to  PA7 - SPI1 MOSI
SCL      to  PA5 - SPI1 SCK

In the case when I send the value 0x8F (1 read bit + 00001111 "WHO_AM_I" address), I get the result as shown below. At the same time I should get the value 0x69 or 01101001 in binary form. And if you look carefully at the results below, you will see that something is interfering, the pulse is too short to be recorded.


For some reason I can't insert the table of registers that is in clause 9.11 "WHO_AM_I (0Fh)", so here is the link:
(https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/796179/STMICROELECTRONICS/LSM6DS3.html)
I tried to read the value in another register "CTRL9_XL" and there the same situation. I should get 00111000, but I got 00110000, as if the pulses were compressed and recorded one less value:


    //SPI config:

    void SpiConfig(void){

    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1 << 12);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////// //////////
    SPI1->CR1 |= (1 << 0) | (1 << 1); //CPHA=1 CPOL=1
    SPI1->CR1 |= (1 << 2); //Master mod
    SPI1->CR1 |= (2 << 3); //010: fPCLK/8 BR[2:0] 5 MHz SPI CLK
    SPI1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 7); //LSBFIRST = 0 => MSB first, then LSB
    SPI1->CR1 |= (1 << 8 ) | (1 << 9); //High level SSI and SSM Software control enabled
    SPI1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 10); //RXONLY = 0 => Full duplex mode
    SPI1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 11); //8-bit
    SPI1->CR2 = 0;
    }

    //GPIO config:

    void SpiGPIOConfig(void){
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= (1 << 0); //Enable RCC for GPIO_A
    GPIOA->MODER |= (2 << 10) | (2 << 12) | (2 << 14) | (1 << 8);
    //Alternative function for PA5/6/7 common output for PA4
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(1 << 9); //Push-Pull for PA5/6/7/4 (default)
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= (3 << 10) | (3 << 12) | (3 << 14) | (3 << 8); //High speed for PA5/6/7/4
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (5 << 20) | (5 << 24) | (5 << 28); //AF5 (AFRL 0 - 7) on PA5/6/7

    }

    //Transmit:

    void SPI_Transmit (uint8_t *data, int size){

    //1. Wait for the TXE bit to be set in the registration state
    int i = 0;
    while(i < size){

    while (!((SPI1->SR) & (1 << 1))){}; //Wait for the TXE bit to be set -> This indicates that the buffer is empty
    SPI1->DR = data[i]; //Load the data into the data register
    i++;
    }
    while(!((SPI1->SR) & (1 << 1))){}; //Wait for the TXE bit to be set -> This indicates that the buffer is empty
    while(((SPI1->SR) & (1 << 7))){}; //Wait for the BSY bit to clear -> This means that the SPIs are not busy with communications

    uint8_t temp = SPI1->DR;
    temperature = SPI1->SR;

    }

    //Main function:

    uint8_t RxData[6];
    address uint8_t = 0x8f;
    while(1){

    CS_EN(); // pull the pin low
    SPI_Transmit (&address, 1); // send the address
    SPI_Receive (RxData, 1); // get 1 byte of data
    CS_DIS(); // pull the pin high

    Delay_ms(1);
    }

If you need to provide something else to find the error, then tell me, I will provide everything you need

Can you show what SPI_Receive() does? After sending the address byte, you need to transmit one byte dummy in order to get the received data back.

Can't see anything obviously wrong, so here are some ideas you could try to debug this. 1: Set the entirety of SPI CR1, just to be sure of the flags. 2: Try lower speed (also would make analyzer output less jittery). 3: Try disconnecting MISO from the MCU and checking with scope if behaviour changes at all. 4: Try bidirectional 2 byte transmit&receive - maybe the device doesn't like big clock gaps for some reason?

You can always to look into the implementation of the driver for Linux kernel to get some ideas from. The code there is most likely was tested (okay, to some extent).
